# Show string on UnicodeError

Tags: python, unicode

If you get a unicode error, it is sometimes hard to find the root of the problem. Where does this string come from?

Is there a way to show the string (or part of buggy string)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this snippet:

```
try:
    html = html.decode(encoding)
except UnicodeError as exc:
    re_raise_unicode_error_with_hint(exc)

def re_raise_unicode_error_with_hint(exc):
    hint = exc.object[max(exc.start - 15, 0):min(exc.end + 15, len(exc.object))]
    raise exc.__class__(exc.encoding, exc.object, exc.start, exc.end, 'hint: %r' % hint)
```

This way you see 15 chars before and 15 chars after the unicode error of your string.

Comment: This hides the exception class (UnicodeDecodeError vs UnicodeEncodeError), which can sometimes be crucial to understanding the bug.  I suggest `raise exc.__class__('%s hint: %r' % (exc, hint))`.